# Finding the number of elements in $\left(ℤ[i]\right)_m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

If $m$ = $m_1$ + $m_1i$ ∈ $ℤ[i]$, is there a general formula to find the number of elements in $\left(ℤ[i]\right)_m$?

Comment: Assuming you mean the subscript to mean "modulo" the number $m_1+m_2i$, the answer is just the norm:  $m_1^2+m_2^2$

Comment: What do you mean by $(\Bbb Z[i])_m$? If it is what Adam is saying, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785522/number-of-elements-in-the-ring-mathbb-z-iota-langle-22-iota-rangle/785680#785680).

Comment: @PedroTamaroff m stands for the modulus

Comment: @Chris That doesn't clear things up, really. Well, maybe. Do you mean $\Bbb Z[i]/(m)$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Are you really asking OP if he means the $m$-adic completion, which is necessarily infinite? You know what he means, and suggesting the correct meaning might help him communicate his question, rather than frustrating him.

Comment: In particular, quite a lot of books use $\mathbb Z_n$ to mean the integers modulo $n$, and likewise for Gaussian integers. To confuse him because he isn't using your preferred notation seems unkind. @PedroTamaroff

Comment: @PedroTamaroff yes thats what I mean

Comment: You might find this previous discussion useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers/874223#874223.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No, I wasn't asking about the $m$-adic completion. I had a very good guess of what he meant, but I didn't want to assume it was that until the OP clarified. Notations vary wildly!

Comment: Right, but look at the question What could he mean? He came here for help, *help* him, don't ask cryptic questions. Do you think he knows what you mean by changing $m$ to $(m)$? Just ask, "Do you mean $\mathbb Z[i]$ modulo $m$?"