# no. of elements in $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 3+i\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

$\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 3+i\rangle$ can be represented as :$\{a+3b+\langle 3+i\rangle\big|~~a,b\in \mathbb Z\}$

How shall I find the total no. of elements in $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 3+i\rangle$..

please provide some hint how should I proceed?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/785680/121097) solves your question and all the other particular questions like yours. In other words, this is the most asked question on M.SE, so you can use SEARCH.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $3 = -i$ in the given ring